# Heroku doesn't display images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3

I've spend whole day try to solved this problem. I solved half way but I couldn't fix the rest. I'm practicing to upload images utilizing Rails framework and deploy the site to Heroku and store images to S3 Amazonaws.

I'm able to store the image to S3 but Heroku doesn't display the image on website.

I noted that S3 Amazonaws and Heroku image display not same Links.

**S3 stored the image under this link:**

*https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/pictures333/pins/images/000/000/024/original/S.Newman__A_Place_of_Inspiration__2017__Oil_on_Canvas__36x48___3500.jpg
https://momo333.herokuapp.com/pins/29*

**Heroku website displays the image under this link:**

*https://s3.amazonaws.com/pictures333/pins/images/000/000/030/medium/S.Newman__A_Place_of_Inspiration__2017__Oil_on_Canvas__36x48___3500.jpg?1511148393"*

In inspector I tested by adding the aws-region part '-us-west-1' between the 's3' and 'amazonaws' and it displays the image.

However, I am not sure how I should modify the links permanently either from S3 Amazon or in my Rails code.

**In Gemfile:**

```
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.3', '>= 4.3.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'haml', '~> 5.0', '>= 5.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
gem 'simple_form', '~> 3.5'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.3'
# gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1'
gem 'masonry-rails', '~> 0.2.4'
gem 'acts_as_votable', '~> 0.11.1'
gem 'will_paginate-bootstrap', '~> 1.0', '>= 1.0.1'
# gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.1'
# gem 'aws-sdk', '2.10.47'
# gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 3.0.0.rc7'
# gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2.10', '>= 2.10.86'
# gem "rails", ">= 4.2"
gem "paperclip", ">= 5.0"
gem "aws-sdk", ">= 2.0"


group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger    console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
   # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
 # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %>   anywhere in the code.
 gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
 gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the  background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
 gem 'spring'
 gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

 group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
 end

   # Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
  gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**app/view/pins/show.html.haml**

```
  #pin_show.row
     .col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
       .panel.panel-default
         .panel-heading.pin_image
          = image_tag @pin.image.url(:medium)
   .panel-body
     %h1= @pin.title
      %p.description= @pin.description
      %p
       Submiited by:
       = @pin.user.email 
   .panel-footer
    .row
      .col-md-6
        %p.user
        Submitted by
        = @pin.user.email
      .col-md-6
        .btn-group.pull-right
          = link_to like_pin_path(@pin), method: :put, class:'btn btn-default' do
            %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-heart
              = @pin.get_upvotes.size
          - if user_signed_in?
            = link_to "Back", root_path, class:'btn btn-default'
            = link_to "Edit", edit_pin_path, class:'btn btn-default'
            = link_to "Delete", pin_path, method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class:'btn btn-default'
```

I'd appreciated your answer, thanks!!!

Comment: I solved the problem by myself. I added # config/initializers/paperclip.rb
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:s3_host_name] = 's3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com'

Comment: You can paste your solution as your answer below.